# Data structure for non-empty set/list

Tags: ocaml

Does there exist a library in OCaml which supports data structures which are non-empty? For example a non-empty list or non-empty set?

Answer (score 2):

I personally didn't ever found one, and created my [own one](https://github.com/BinaryAnalysisPlatform/bap/blob/master/src/server/list1.mli).

Comment: The structure `list1` is not very good because of the `tl` operation which is not well defined in our case. It would be better to drop it and add `iter` and `fold` operations to the interface,

Comment: Indeed, `tail` should be either removed, or made optional, since it doesn't preserve the non-empty list invariant.  Also, `iter` and `fold`, as well as `map` and everything else are in the interface, they are included in the `Container.S1`.